# angular $http post not sending data for service

Tags: angularjs, post, service

I´m trying user $http post in angular, where the rest service receive an object. The data is a Json where I need pass with parameter for method in service.

My angular code (it´s doesn´t work for me):

```
   $http({
       method:'POST',
       url:request.url,
       data: JSON.stringify(objcsr);

       headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

       }).then(function(objS){

           alert('Success :-    '+JSON.stringify(objS));
       },function(objE){
          debugger;
           alert('error:-    '+JSON.stringify(objE));

       });
```

If I comment the row data, the comunication with service it´s ok:

```
   $http({
       method:'POST',
       url:request.url,
       //data: JSON.stringify(objcsr);

       headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

       }).then(function(objS){

           alert('Success :-    '+JSON.stringify(objS));
       },function(objE){
          debugger;
           alert('error:-    '+JSON.stringify(objE));

       });
```

My method in service:

```
    public UserAccessDTO Authenticate(AuthenticationDTO authentication)
    {
          .....

      }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I also tried to pass json directly, data: objcsr, but doesn´t work. 
I do not get error, just does not call the service method. If I comment data the service is called but the method parameter is null

Answer (score 0):

I hope the object you are passing in `data` parameter is same as `AuthenticationDTO` class, its properties must be same. If that is fine then try running this.

```
$http.post('url',JSON.stringify(data),{headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}})
.success(function (data) {
                alert('Success :-    '+JSON.stringify(data));
            });
```

As well I am assuming that you have included `[HttpPost]` attribute before your method. like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public UserAccessDTO Authenticate(AuthenticationDTO authentication)
    {
          .....

    }
```

Comment: Yes, the object in data is same as AuthenticationDTO class. I try your solution, but This way even without the data does not call the service.

Comment: You must be getting an error, what is that error ? Try to see in browser console

Comment: check modified answer. Please check that you have added [HttpPost] attribute.

Comment: Where check [HttPost] in my service (c#)? I´m using in C#: [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Authenticate", Method ="Post", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Comment: Try to find an error in browser console, if console is empty then go to Network tab, and check you request log in the list, you will be able to see an error there

Comment: The error is: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:2582/Core.svc/Authenticate. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405. But This error happens in all situations

Comment: Ok got it, now try adding this line before that method
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Comment: I put [EnableCors(origins: "", headers: "", methods: "*")], doesn´t work

Comment: Are you able to call other APIs ?

Comment: I don´t have other api, but a in my example without data call the api.
 $http({
       method:'POST',
       url:request.url,
       //data: JSON.stringify(objcsr);

       headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

       }).then(function(objS){

           alert('Success :-    '+JSON.stringify(objS));
       },function(objE){
          debugger;
           alert('error:-    '+JSON.stringify(objE));

       });